# Fetching Realtime Database in Cloud Function return the wrong object

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to fetch data from my Realtime database but when I do, it return my this object:

> {"domain":{"domain":null,"_events":{},"_eventsCount":3,"members":[]}} instead of something like this: {0: 'user1', 1: 'user2'}.

There is a screen from my Realtime database:

[image: realtime databse]

My code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.getProductTypeUpdate = functions.database
    .ref("Products/{product}/type")
    .onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {
      const type = snapshot.after.val();
      console.log("Product type created: " + type);
      const users = admin.database().ref("Notif/type/" + type)
          .once("value").then((snapshot) => {
            return snapshot.val();
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
            return false;
          });
      console.log("Users fetched are: " + JSON.stringify(users));
      const result = {etat: "create", users: users};
      console.log("Final result is: " + JSON.stringify(result));
      return result;
    });
```

And the "error" (it's write in french but it's not important):

[image: wrong object]

Thank you for help !

Comment: What is the output if you `console.log(snapshot.val())` **inside** the `then` callback?

Comment: The output is: [user1, user2] ! It's what I want, maybe I need to remove the JSON.stringify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `users` variable is actually a `Promise`. To log it inside the code, you have to either `await` it, or use `then()`.

It's probably easiest to start using `async` and `await` here, which would make your code look like this:

```
exports.getProductTypeUpdate = functions.database
  .ref("Products/{product}/type")
  .onUpdate(async (snapshot, context) => {
          // 
    const type = snapshot.after.val();
    try {
      const snapshot = await admin.database().ref("Notif/type/" + type).once("value");
      let users = snapshot.val();
      const result = {etat: "create", users: users};
      return result;
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log("Error sending message:", error);
      return false;
    }
  });
```

I also recommend reading the Firebase documentation on [sync, async, promises and how to terminate functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions), and the MDN documentation on [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises#async_and_await).

Answer (score 0):

I did it but I think my Node.js version was not able to run ES6, I get messages like "Unexpected token", so I did that and now it works:

```
exports.getProductTypeUpdate = functions.database
.ref("Products/{product}/type")
.onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {
  // on récupère le type du produit
  const type = snapshot.after.val();
  console.log("Le type du produit créé est: " + type);
  // on récupère les utilisateurs interresse par le type d'objet
  admin.database().ref("Notif/type/" + type)
      .once("value").then((snapshot) => {
        const users = snapshot.val();
        console.log("Les utilisateurs dans " +
        "le snapshot sont:" + snapshot.val());
        console.log("Les utilisateurs tirés sont: " + users);
        // Retourne les utilisateurs à notifier et l'état de la requête
        const result = {state: "create", users: users};
        console.log("Le résultat final est: " + JSON.stringify(result));
        return result;
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        return false;
      });
});
```